# Does any one know how to randomize rows of a dataframe of pandas with some constraints?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, random

I have a pandas frame with two columns, column A and column B.
What I want to do is to randomize the rows of this dataframe, and no same values in column B are on adjacent rows.

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  3  1
3  4  2
4  5  2
5  6  2
6  7  3
7  8  3
```

What come up to me is that I can sameple one row a time which satisfy this constraints, i.e., sample one row with its value in column B equals to 1, then sample another row with its value in column B  equals to 2 or 3.

However, this solution requires multiple for loops, especially when the constraints involve more than one column B.

So, does any one know better solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really **randomization** as the logic is fully deterministic, but ordering the rows by their position in each group would satisfy your requirement:

```
import numpy as np

out = df.iloc[np.argsort(df.groupby('B').cumcount().to_numpy())]
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  1  1
3  4  2
6  7  3
1  2  1
4  5  2
7  8  3
2  3  1
5  6  2
```

Comment: Many thanks! However, I do not want values in Column B to follow an ascending or descending order. It could be a sequence of 1 2 1 3 2 3 1 2, or other sequences.

Comment: @finch do you mean that you do not **necessarily** want them in a given order? Or you want to **ensure they are not**? In which case you need to better explain the logic. As of the current state of the question, I believed my answer addresses your requirements

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity.  As you said, I want to ensure that the values in column B do not follow any order and that the same values in column B are not on adjacent rows. For example, column B could be like 2 3 1 3 2 1, but should not be like 2 3 3 1 1 2.

Comment: We'll my solution already gives you the non-identical successive. A further "non-ordered" seems an anti-pattern without a clear described logic so I don't have a solution for that.